# "listen" or "hear" in this situation

Tags: word-difference

Suppose that in a computer application you hear a word that is spoken by the computer and you must spell it. Now if you can click on a button to hear the word again what do you say:

- You can click "Say again" button **to listen to** the word again. Or
- You can click "Say again" button **to hear** the word again.

Comment: Either _listen to_ or _hear_ could work, but _"Say again" is a little awkward.  _Repeat_ sounds a little cleaner.  _Click the "Repeat" button to listen to the word again.  Click the "Repeat" button to hear the word again._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use:

> You (can) click "Say again" button **to hear** the word again.

Because you would be "hearing" the word. Whether you are listening to the word or not is another matter. Meaning the button can't make you listen.

I used *can* because I assume it is the users option.

Answer (score 0):

The computer dictates the word which the user must write down, it therefore stands to reason that the button should be simply renamed ‘word’.

- To [***rehear***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/rehear), click on the ‘word’ button. (7 words)

A shortcut approach would be to use the word *relisten*, which means “listen again”

- In order to *[**relisten**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/relisten)*, click on the ‘word’ button. (9 words)

Oxford Dictionaries list both verbs and suggest that they are interchangeable.

Answer (score -1):

Get rid of "can".

The instruction is elliptical for:

If you wish to listen to the word again, you must click the button to have the computer say the word again.

**To listen to the word again, click the `Say Again` button.**